# Is it possible to have permalinks to sub-domain pages and to root pages within one single WP instance?

Tags: plugins, permalinks, subdomains

I am trying to figure out if I can build pages referenced by permalinks to
abc.mydomain.com - and - to mydomain.com in a single WP instance.

I would prefer having only 1 WP instance for the pages under the root domain and for the pages under the sub-domain.

Maybe a plugin could do the trick?

If not, I will need 2 different WP instance.

Comment: You could create a multisite network to use a single WordPress install for two sites. Plugins, themes, and users would be shared, but content and settings would be separate for each: https://wordpress.org/support/article/create-a-network/

Comment: Is it be possible to activate a different theme for each site?